# Convert each array into objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am new to javascript. How ever i am not familiar with arrays and objects that much. I got stuck with it now.

I have an array like this.

`[ '5', '13', '16', '22', '24' ]` 1st  <-- code for this

im trying to achieve like the one below

```
[null,{
            "0": 5,
            "1": "FFFRRR",
            "tx": 0,
            "ty": 0,
            "tz": 0,
            "rx": 0,
            "ry": 0,
            "rz": 0
        },
        {
            "0": 13,
            "1": "FFFRRR",
            "tx": 0,
            "ty": 0,
            "tz": 0,
            "rx": 0,
            "ry": 0,
            "rz": 0
        },
        {
            "0": 16,
            "1": "FFFRRR",
            "tx": 0,
            "ty": 0,
            "tz": 0,
            "rx": 0,
            "ry": 0,
            "rz": 0
        },
        {
            "0": 22,
            "1": "FFFRRR",
            "tx": 0,
            "ty": 0,
            "tz": 0,
            "rx": 0,
            "ry": 0,
            "rz": 0
        },
        {
            "0": 24,
            "1": "FFFRRR",
            "tx": 0,
            "ty": 0,
            "tz": 0,
            "rx": 0,
            "ry": 0,
            "rz": 0
        }]
```

thanks for those who will help.

Comment: Look at the [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2) methods available to you. Hint: `map`. All of your objects are identical except for the value of the `0` property. Try something, then ask a specific question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each code, you want to map an object. `Array.prototype.map` is perfect for this kind of treatment.

```
const codes = ['5', '13', '16', '22', '24'];

const mappedObjects = codes.map(code => {
    return {
        '0': Number(code),
        '1': 'FFFRRR',
        tx: 0,
        ty: 0,
        tz: 0,
        rx: 0,
        ry: 0,
        rz: 0,
    };
});
```

Comment: thanks mate i was kinda researching this for about  half a day and can't  find the answer until you showed up. The code worked

Comment: how to put it in a function?

Comment: `function objectsFromCodes(codes) {   return codes.map(code => ...); }`

Comment: sergio how did you paste that long code? i can't post mine like that. here in the comments